# Can I refill my health while defeating the rats?

Tags: candy-box-2

In **Candy Box 2,** the person living in the house on the top right corner wants me to kill the rats in his cellar, so I did. When I was fighting the rats, my health was getting pretty low, so I wanted to eat candies to refill my health. But I couldn't. Is it because candies don't refill my health, or is it because I can't just refill my health while fighting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eating candies does not refill your health.

You can get items later that will periodically restore your health in quests, throw candy in the wishing well to heal yourself, craft potions from candies to use in quests or just idle for your health to restore.

Answer (score 3):

No, but if you can't beat it, try eating your candy, before hand. It will increase your max HP